# NDepend Get Third Party references for each project in solution

Tags: ndepend

For each project in my solution, I want to get a list of which third-party assemblies it uses.

I guess something like this:

```
    let landscapeAssemblies = from a in JustMyCode.Assemblies
    let thirdPartyAssemblies = from a in ThirdParty.Assemblies

    select new { landscapeAssemblies, thirdPartyAssemblies.UsedBy(landscapeAssemblies) }
```

But (like most of my ndepend queries) I get the error "Incomplete Query" - I have no Idea how that query isn't complete.

What I want to be returned is something like:

```
Project1 :
          Third Party Assembly 1
          Third Party Assembly 2
          Third Party Assembly 3
Project2:
          etc
          etc
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this query meets your need?

```
from a in Application.Assemblies
let thirdPartyAsmUsed = ThirdParty.Assemblies.UsedBy(a)
select new { a, thirdPartyAsmUsed }
```

[image: Third-Party assemblies used by each application assembly]

And with a bit of astute, when you are in diff mode, you can ask for each assembly of your application, which third-party assemblies is newly used since the diff baseline :)

```
from a in Application.Assemblies
where a.IsPresentInBothBuilds()
let thirdPartyAsmUsedNew = ThirdParty.Assemblies.UsedBy(a)
let thirdPartyAsmUsedOld = codeBase.OlderVersion().ThirdParty.Assemblies.UsedBy(a.OlderVersion())
let thirdPartyAsmNewlyUsed =  thirdPartyAsmUsedNew.Except(
                 thirdPartyAsmUsedOld.Where(m=> m.IsPresentInBothBuilds()).Select(m => m.NewerVersion()))
select new { a, thirdPartyAsmUsedNew, thirdPartyAsmUsedOld, thirdPartyAsmNewlyUsed }
```

[image: Third Party assemblies newly used by each application assembly]